# Intellij: How do I run a single method from my python script instead of running main

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have written a script foo.py.
In the method there is a method:

```
def bar(p1, p2):
  print("this is bar:" + p1 + ", " + p2)
```

is there a way to run only the bar method with my desired inputs, instead of running main()?

Comment: `bar(1, 2)`?...

Comment: IntelliJ cannot run specific function from your Python file. Open Python console, import your method e.g. `from foo import bar` and call it as you like.